# Cleaning up a method call

Tags: java, java-8

Given the following code:

```
String s = "dirty";
for (Action action : actions) {
  s = doAction(s, action);
}
```

...where **Actions** can be a cleaning operation on the string such as removing illegal chars or removing a duplicate word.

Is there a way to write this more elegantly to handle the call without reassigning the string?

Comment: Is this really recursive? Please give us more context to work with.

Comment: What recursive call? Is this inside a function called `doAction`?

Comment: where are you doing recursive method call?

Comment: That doesn't look like a recursive call which is typically of the format f(n) = f(n-1) + something until you get to a base case of f(0) or f(1)

Comment: Most likely not, as `String`s aren't mutable, so it'll have to be reassigned whenever changes to it are made, otherwise it would just be discarded.  If you want to change `String` to `StringBuilder`, then sure.

Comment: I meant calling a method repeatedly with the output of that method but perhaps I misunderstood recursion.

Comment: @AndyCribbens yes, recursion is about a method calling itself until a condition is met and then return the answer, see my answer for an example

Comment: @Bentaye *Recursion doesn't have to stop based on a condition at any point. Infinitely recursing functions are pretty common. I think it would be better to just define recursion as when function calls itself, or more generally, something that's defined in terms of itself. A petty correction, but I wouldn't want to confuse the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid reassigning the string as you need the updated value in each iteration.

As for:

> Is there a way to write this more elegantly

Using the streams API, you could do:

```
String result = actions.stream() // or Arrays.stream(actions)
                       .reduce("dirty", (s, action ) -> doAction(s, action),
                                (e, a) -> {throw new RuntimeException("un-implemented");});
```

Although it's arguably not as readable as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive way to write it would be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Action> actions = .. //your list of Actions
    String s = doActions("dirty", actions);
}

private static String doActions(String s, List<Action> actions) {
    if(actions.isEmpty()) {
        return s;
    } else {
        // apply the first Action
        Action action = actions.remove(0);
        String newString = doAction(s, action);
        // recursively call with the new String and the remaining actions
        return doActions(newString, actions);
    }
}
```

But as you can see, you still get a string `creation/assignement` in the `doActions` method. This is due to the fact that `String` is immutable and can't be modified.

If you are just looking for a `recursive` way to write it then that could do. If you really want to get rid of the new `String` creation, you need to use a `StringBuilder`, as Jacob G suggested. With a signature such as

```
void doAction(StringBuilder sb, Action action)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid reassigning `s` by making it a field

```
public class SActions {

    private String s;
    SActions(String s){this.s = s;} 
    public void doAction(Action action){ /* apply action to s */}
    public String getString() { return s; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SActions sActions = new SActions("abc");
        sActions.doAction(anAction);
        System.out.println(sActions.getString());
    }
}
```

You could also add a method to accept a collection of `Actions`:

```
public void doAction(Collection<Action> actions) {
    for (Action action : actions) {
        doAction(action);
    }
}
```

To make the object reusable, add a setter:

```
public SActions setString(String s) {
    this.s = s;
    return this;//for convenience, so you can chain invocation  
}
```

Note that the setter return `this` for more convenient invocation:

```
SActions sActions = new SActions(); //requiers standard constructor
sActions.setString("abc").doAction(anAction);
```

If it is more or less elegant' it is certainly arguable.